# Re-Name Google Drive Images from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Form where people have submitted photos of themselves.
This data has been stored in a spreadsheet.
I want to rename all of the submitted photos to the person's name so that we can tell who is who in the photos - without having to do it manually.

To do this, I have created this script:

```
function reName() {
var sheetName = 'Data';
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName); 
var newName = sheet.getRange("C2:C10");                        
var ID = sheet.getRange("D2:D10");                        
var nameData = newName.getValues();
var idData = ID.getValues();

for (var i = 0, iLen = nameData.length; i < iLen; i++) {

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ID);

file.setName(newName);
   }
}
```

However, it is throwing me the following error message:
'No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it.'
I have tested the script to work on just one image, and Name, which works.
How can I get it to work on the whole range?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems that `newName` and `ID` are in "C2:C10" and "D2:D10", respectively. So how about the following modification?

#### Modification points :

- Data which is retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array.
- Data of "C2:C10" and "D2:D10" can be retrieved to an array.

#### Modified script :

```
function reName() {
  var sheetName = 'Data';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange("C2:D10").getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(data[i][1]);
    file.setName(data[i][0]);
  }
}
```

#### Reference :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked perfectly. I was definitely struggling with getting my head around the arrays.
Cheers.

Comment: @Jesse Gardner-Russell Welcome. Thank you, too.